# Where is the changelog of a Joomla page?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, changelog

I'm new with Joomla, but I should fix some bugs on a page. Do you know, where can I find the changelog of the page? Is there any log, or I have to looking for some extension?

Comment: Changelog of the page? Please be a little more specific

Comment: An admin function, or menu, where the last changes of the page (settings, etc) are listed.

Comment: You seem to have an unusual definition for the word "[changelog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changelog)".

Comment: This feature doesn't come default with Joomla and there are no extensions that I'm aware of that provide such a feature, however there is a plugin currently being developed that will log changes for a couple of things such as articles. I'm unsure when it will be released

Comment: That was my question. Thank you!

Comment: @Elin, Ah it's actually going to be released in 3.2? I thought it was going to be a 3rd party extension

Comment: Yes it is in master already and it's awesome :).

Comment: I look forward to testing this. Would be a good plugin to extend for sure if it's not already based on things such as menu items, users etc

Comment: We released an alpha today, you can try it out. Right now it is doing basic content tables, but it can and will be expanded to other things. It's an extremely flexible API.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to keeping a trace of changes in page formatting, then an external tool such as git or svn will do the trick.

If you however want to monitor changes to the contents of a page (text, title, meta etc), then you want to look into a plugin. I have used com_versions successfully on fairly large sites (3000+ articles 10+ authors) and it worked nicely. No configuration, just a new button in your edit field where you can inspect and choose previous versions.  You can find it here: http://www.fatica.net/extensions/simple-content-versioning.html